# How to approach multi-model form in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a complex form in Ruby on Rails 2.3.5, here's the structure for it:
Artist
  - Name
  - Albums
      -Songs
  - Photos

Each artist can albums and several photos. For each album, there are several songs.
I want to create a 3 step process.
  - Create Artist
  - Create Album (will have option to create multiple songs)
  - Create Photos

I want to set it up in a wizard-like way.
My question is actually pretty general - how would you go about (organizationally speaking) creating forms for the models and controllers for such a project?

Currently, I have a model called Artist, a model called Albums and a model called Photos. Artists has many albums and photos. Under which view would I place the form?

Right now, the way it is looking I go to:
artists/new - create the artist, somehow pass artist id to album,
move to albums as albums/new, keep passing that artist id to photos,
photos/new to create photos and then finish -> back to artists/show.

Ideally, I'd like to have something like artists/new/1 to create the artists
artists/new/2 to create the albums and artists/new/3 to create the photos.

How would I go about doing that? Other than routing the pages to where I want them, is that the correct way of organizing things?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need [nested routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-routes). It automatically should handle relations.

So you will have links like `artists/1/albums/new`, `artists/1/albums/5/songs/new` etc

So your scenario could sound like this:

1. `artsists/new`
2. Save the artist on post.
3. Redirect (or render ajax form) to new article (you can use rails generated helper) `redirect_to new_artist_article_url @artist_just_created_and_saved`
4. Save artist and to the same for songs etc

Comment: this looks promising, yet I am unclear about how to work it out when I am first creating an artist - I won't have its id yet. What would I do?

Comment: Updated answer a bit with the details.

Comment: ust have a look at the link I provided. Read it through (especially nested *RESOURCES*) and you will be fine